Why don't monitored Proxmox hypervisor hosts show up in the 'Top hosts by CPU utilization' Zabbix dashoard widget?
I have a couple of PVE hosts being monitored by Zabbix using the 'Proxmox VE by HTTP' template but they don't show up in the 'Top hosts by CPU utilization' dashboard widget.
I added the Hypervisor host group to the widget but that didn't work. I added the individual PVE hosts to the widget but that failed too.
How do I cause these hosts to show up in this widget?

When I examined the host config for the one server that always did appear in the widget no matter its load, (the Zabbix server) I noticed it had the 'Linux by Zabbix agent' template attached to it.
So I applied the 'Linux by Zabbix agent' template to the PVE hosts and voila. The PVE hosts now appear in the 'Top hosts by CPU utilization' dashboard widget.

Can you please tell me how you managed to add PVE Hosts in 'Top hosts by CPU utilization'. I already have a Proxmox cluster successfully connected to Zabbix via Proxmox API. I am struggling to figure out how to show up Proxmox hosts in 'Top hosts by CPU utilization' widget. I tried to add 'Linux by Zabbix agent' with 'Proxmox VE by HTTP' template in Proxmox VE host (that is connected using Proxmox API) but it just stopped working. I think I need to add hosts seperately using Proxmox API but I am stuck here.
